# How to do tree traversal?

Tags: python, tree-traversal, inorder

So I am running into some issue that has left me dumbfounded. I do not understand where I am going wrong with my code but the idea I have is I check if the current node I am at is `None` and if it is then I return a list of my tree in **in order**, **pre order**, and **post order**. Here is my code:

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.left = None
    self.right = None

  def inOrder(self, arr=[]):
    if self is not None:
      self.left.inOrder(arr)
      arr.append(self.data)
      self.right.inOrder(arr)

    return arr
```

When I run it I get an error of  `self.left.inOrder() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'inOrder'` which I have not idea as to why. I am checking that `self is not None` so shouldn't this guarantee my `Node` to have a `left` and `right`.

I am only showing the **inOrder** I have implemented.

I have solved this instead by doing the following

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def inOrder(self):
        if self is not None and self.left is not None:
            self.left.inOrder()

        print(self.data)

        if self is not None and self.right is not None:
            self.right.inOrder()


root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)


root.inOrder()
```

Whether I save it to a list or just print it is fine with me but if I already check if self is not None then shouldn't I be able to call `self.left.inOrder` and `self.right.inOrder`?

Comment: [Think carefully](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) about what happens when the recursion reaches a leaf of the tree. Is `self` equal to `None`? Therefore, will the code in the `if` block run? Therefore, will the recursive calls be attempted? Now - is `self.left` and/or `self.right` equal to `None`? (Hint: how is a leaf defined?) Therefore, what will happen if a recursive call is attempted on that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is not `None`. `self` refers to an instance of the class.  `self.left` is an instance attribute that you set to `None` in your `__init__()` method when you create the instance. Because `self.left` refers to `None` and the object `None` does not have the `inOrder()` method, you obtain an `AttributeError`. Within your class definition, `self` (referring to an instance of the class) does have the `inOrder()` method, but it's attribute `self.left` (referring to `None`), does not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see this now actually. I was having an issue trying to understand it at first but of course `None` will not have an `inOrder()`